# Join check view with a calendar view

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two views. One with checks:

```
Check_Id    Issued_Date    Cleared_Date   Amount
1           2017.01.03     2017.02.04    100
2           2017.03.03     2017.04.04    100
3           2017.08.03                   100
...
```

And another is just a calendar:

```
Day
2001.01.01
2001.01.02
2001.01.03
...
2100.12.31
```

I need a scaffold view for Tableau. What i'd like to achieve is, for every check, have a record in the dates between Issued date to the cleared date. If there is no cleared date, just go to the end of times (2100.12.31 in this case).

Ie, for the Check_id 1:

```
Day        Check_ID
2017.01.03 1
2017.01.03 1
2017.01.03 1
2017.01.03 1
...
2017.02.04 1
2017.08.03 3
2017.08.04 3
2017.08.05 3
2017.08.06 3
...
2100.12.31 3
```

Any tip or stuff i'd read to get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-equijoin:

```
select ca.day, c.check_id
from checks c join
     calendar ca
     on ca.day >= c.issued_date  and
        (c.cleared_date is null or c.cleared_date >= ca.date);
```